# Ros install on OSX help?

Tags: ros, homebrew, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS on my Mac. Using the instructions provided for the mac homebrew installation (obviously). I get through to step 3.1 and then get hung up on running cmake step. The configuration however does not finish. I get several warnings but only one error. Here is my report. -- +++ catkin -- Found gtest: gtests will be built. TODO: implement add_roslaunch_check() in rostest-extras.cmake. -- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on. -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -- ~~ traversing stacks/projects in dependency order ~~ -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -- +++ genmsg -- +++ genlisp -- +++ genpy -- +++ gencpp -- +++ std_msgs -- std_msgs: 32 messages -- +++ rospack -- Rospack building shared objects. -- +++ ros -- Making toplevel forward script for bash script rosrun -- +++ roscpp_core -- +++ ros_comm -- rosgraph_msgs: 2 messages -- std_srvs: 0 messages TODO: consider moving xmlrpcpp's headers into a subdirectory -- roscpp: 1 messages -- topic_tools: 0 messages CMake Warning at build/cmake/rosunit/rosunit-extras.cmake:17 (message): add_pyunit() is deprecated. For Python tests, use add_nostests() instead. Call Stack (most recent call first): ros_comm/tools/topic_tools/CMakeLists.txt:70 (add_pyunit)

CMake Warning at build/cmake/rosunit/rosunit-extras.cmake:17 (message): add_pyunit() is deprecated. For Python tests, use add_nostests() instead. Call Stack (most recent call first): ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeLists.txt:62 (add_pyunit)

-- test_ros: 15 messages -- test_roslib_comm: 15 messages -- test_rospy: 12 messages -- test_rosservice: 0 messages -- test_roscpp: 4 messages -- test_roscpp_serialization: 18 messages -- test_roscpp_serialization_perf: 3 messages -- perf_roscpp: 2 messages -- test_crosspackage: 2 messages -- test_rosbag: 12 messages CMake Warning at build/cmake/rosunit/rosunit-extras.cmake:17 (message): add_pyunit() is deprecated. For Python tests, use add_nostests() instead. Call Stack (most recent call first): ros_comm/test/test_rosbag/CMakeLists.txt:52 (add_pyunit)

-- +++ rx CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.8/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE): Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_FOUND) Call Stack (most recent call first): /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.8/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.8/share/cmake/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:831 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS) rx/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36649/ros-install-on-osx-help?/) by [BigRed_61](https://answers.ros.org/users/2631/bigred_61/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-06-17**:
Is wxwidgets installed?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-06-18**:
Which OS X are you running (lion, snow leopard, leopard, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is failing because you don't have wxWidgets installed.  Even with wxWidgets installed, I am not sure the rx stack works on OS X right now.  You can skip building it by deleting the rx folder.  I would recommend Electric at the moment for OS X anyways.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1